# Использовать метод Монте-Карло для нахождения числа π

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется такая задача : нужно использовать метод Монте-Карло для нахождения числа **π** . Из входных данных имеется 1 миллион точек и 5000 итераций, после которых получается среднее арифметическое всех значений **π**.

Если с нахождением числа **π** проблем никаких не возникает, то как автоматически обновлять всю таблицу и одновременно с этим записывать сумму каждых последующих итераций в некую ячейку?

[image: Таблица]

Используемые формулы:

```
A2=СЛЧИС()
B2=СЛЧИС()
С2=ЕСЛИ((A2^2+B2^2)<=1;1;0)
D2=СУММ(C2:C1000002) 
E2=СЧЁТ(C2:C1000002)
F2=D2*4/E2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Макрос VBA**

```
Sub IterationAndMonteCarloMethod()
    Dim dSum As Double, Quantity As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Const NumberOfSteps As Long = 1000 ' к-во значений '
    Const IterationsCount As Long = 500 ' к-во итераций '
    
    Randomize
    
    For i = 1 To IterationsCount
        Quantity = 0
        
        For n = 1 To NumberOfSteps
            If Rnd ^ 2 + Rnd ^ 2 <= 1 Then Quantity = Quantity + 1
        Next n
        
        If Quantity > 0 Then dSum = dSum + Quantity * 4 / NumberOfSteps
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print "Сумма: " & dSum
    If IterationsCount > 0 Then Debug.Print "Среднее: " & dSum / IterationsCount
End Sub
```

Но при 1000000*5000 будет работать ой как долго...

Результат смотреть в окне `Immediate` в редакторе VBA

---

Инструмент  **Итеративные вычисления** предназначен для точных вычислений (например, геодезических). Его "фишка" - разрешенные зацикливания вычислений. Применение итераций для данной задачи - это больше познавательный вариант, чем практический.

Использование итеративных вычислений имеет ряд подводных камней: при включении/выключении итераций эта настройка применяется для всех открытых книг; можно пропустить нежелательные зацикливания вычислений. Но если открыта только одна книга и в ней нет других вычислений, кроме конкретных расчетов с применением этого инструмента, то опасаться нечего.

Большой минус этого варианта для данной задачи - пересчет 5000 раз 2 млн случайных чисел займет много времени. Например, запуск 100 итераций (50 вычислений) - около 1 минуты (зависит от мощности железа). Но если есть другое занятие, то минус превращается в большой плюс - запустить расчет и вскопать за это время сотку земли или разгрузить грузовик цемента :)

*`Файл-Параметры-Формулы-Параметры вычислений`* -установить галку *`Включить итеративные вычисления`*, *`Предельное число итераций`* = 10000 - *`OK`* (10000 - потому что сумма будет вычисляться через одну итерацию)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`F4` - флаг сброса суммы, или иначе: *разрешение счета* (любое ненулевое число)/*запрет счета* (пусто или ноль).

`F5` - триггер (переключатель), 1/0:

```
=--ЕСЛИ(F4;F5=0;)
```

`F6` - счет шагов:

```
=ЕСЛИ(F4;ЕСЛИ(F5;F6+1;F6);)
```

`F7` - накопительное суммирование чисел, вычисленных в каждой итерации:

```
=ЕСЛИ(F4;ЕСЛИ(F5;F2+F7;F7);)
```

`F8` - формула среднего:

```
=ЕСЛИ(F4;F7/F6;)
```

Также необходимо изменить формулы генерации случайных чисел (естественно, протянуть до строки 1000002):

```
A2 =ЕСЛИ($F$5=0;СЛЧИС();A2)
B2 =ЕСЛИ($F$5=0;СЛЧИС();B2)
```

При `F4 = 0` (или `F4` пусто) сумма и среднее не вычисляются. При `F4 = 1`(или `F4<>0`) запускаются итерации.

Триггер принимает значения 0 или 1. При нуле генерируются случайные числа, на следующем шаге к накопленной сумме добавляется вычисленное значение.

При каждой итерации вычисляется среднее значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, что заморочились над такой задачкой =) Не ожидал получить ответ через три месяца :)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете формулы, то они (по умолчанию) автоматически обновляются, при изменении данных. Также можно запросить перерасчет в ручную, клавишей **F9**.

Если у вас не происходит автоматический перерасчет, то стоит обратить внимание на следующую ссылку: [Автоматический пересчет формул в Excel и вручную](https://exceltable.com/formuly/avtomaticheskiy-pereschet-formul)

**UPD:** есть формула СЛМАССИВ, с ее помощью вы можете сразу генерировать необходимое вам количество элементов в двумерном массиве, но даже 1ккХ5к массив мне excel не дал сделать (закончились ресурсы). Единственный вариант я вижу - работа с VBA

Comment: Да, они обновляются, но мне нужно, чтобы это обновление происходило 5000 раз, суммировало и выводило среднее арифметическое всех чисел автоматически. В ручную 5000 раз тыкать кнопку и записывать данные очень долго =)

Comment: @Индюк дополните свой вопрос пожалуйста. Добавьте скрины, пример данных, пример ваших действий. Вопрос не в том, как обновлять, а как вы пользуетесь формулами.

Comment: @Индюк могу лишь предложить вариант транспонировать ваши X и Y, чтобы они были в строку и повторить эти строки по 5000 раз, а на отдельном листе рассчитывать суммы для каждой пары строк и рядом выводить общий итог. Также есть вариант реализовать макрос, который сразу посчитает вам все что нужно без дополнительной записи в ячейки.

Comment: Идея с макросами более интересна. Повторить таблицу с миллионом ячеек 5000 раз, думаю, сломает Excel =)